# How to create a column in MYSQL which automatically SUMs the values from other columns within the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

Could anybody tell me whether it is possible to have a column within a table in MYSQL that automatically performs the SUM function for a given number of columns.

As a comparative example in Microsoft Excel, it's possible to have a cell that performs the SUM function for a given range of cells and automatically updates `i.e. (=SUM E4:E55)`

Is it possible to have a column which achieves the same function in MYSQL?

To further elaborate -

I have numerous columns relating to the quantity of different sizes of our products i.e. `quantity_size_*` and wanted a column that would SUM the value of the quantity columns and update automatically if any of the values are changed.

Any advice would be great. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if there is but if there is not you could use a trigger to do it automatically.

Comment: I think you should change your table design and use i.e. three columns `product, size, quantity`. Imagine you have a new size of your product: you've got not only to alter your table. Your applications must changed too ...

Comment: What Vmai said. Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would do that in your select query on-the-fly and don't store those calculation.

```
select some_column,
       col1 * col2 as some_calculation_result
from your_table
```

But if you have a really good reason not to do it that way then you can use a trigger to calculate those data.

You need an update trigger to catch changes in the data and an insert trigger to calculate on insertion.

An example of an insert trigger goes like this

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER sum_trigger AFTER INSERT ON your_table 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.sum_column = NEW.column1 * NEW.column2;          
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: @marcus: I was using a `*` on purpose since the question mentions a column named `quantity_size_*`.

Comment: How would it be carried out in the select query on-the-fly? If that's the best way of doing? The solution posted above - would that need to be added to every script that alters the quantity column values or just run with PHPMyAdmin once?

Comment: @Aphex22: You need to add this only once to attach the trigger to your table. Same with the update trigger. I updated my answer for an on-the-fly example.

Comment: Thanks Juergen. I think I might need to change my database design in order to take full advantage of TRIGGERS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do this with a trigger.  A column by itself just store data, it can't do things programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Mysql also heve the `SUM()` function which you can use in a select query.
So the best option will be to use a `SELECT SUM()` query 
or else you can even create a `VIEW` for that , but triggers
are not recommended as they may become troublesome.